# disable S0 standby and enable S3 on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, power-management, suspend

This article explains how to disable S0 and replace it by S3 on windows:
https://www.notebookcheck.net/Useful-Life-Hack-How-to-Disable-Modern-Standby-Connected-Standby.453125.0.html

What are the equivalent commands for Ubuntu?
How to check what standby is currently used on Ubuntu and how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://01.org/blogs/qwang59/2018/how-achieve-s0ix-states-linux) Linux does not enable connected standby (`S0ix`) by default and it has to be enabled manually. The same document describes how you can check whether your device supports this standby method.